# Using awk, how to check for patterns from second file in first file and append value to first file depending on pattern existence

Tags: string, file, awk, pattern-matching

data.txt:

```
aaab;10
bbbc;20
abc;30
cc;40
```

pattern.txt:

```
aaa
aa
bbb
ccc
3
c+
```

Wanted output:

```
aaab;10;2
bbbc;20;2
abc;30;1
cc;40;1
```

Hence, if any of the strings in pattern.txt exist in column1 in data.txt, append 2 to data.txt, if not, append 1. The strings can contain letters, numbers, spaces, etc, more or less any character.

Comment: you input file is in inconsistent format, is the delimiter `:` or `;` or both.  Is it intentional that one set has one delimiter at the end of line and other set don't?  Or, oversight?

Comment: @karakfa, you are correct, the delimier should be `;` sorry for the mistake, I have now replaced the `:`with `;` at four places in the original question

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your help, I added data to illustrate additional caes!

Comment: @EdMorton Very good, tried it and it produced false positive, hence, it output the line "cc;40;2" instead of "cc;40;1" (should have output the latter). Thanks so much again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on one possible interpretation of what you've told us so far in the text in your question and in comments, this is probably what you really need:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS=";" }
    NR==FNR { strs[$0]; next }
    { c=1; for (str in strs) if (index($1,str)) {c=2; break} print $0, c }
' patterns.txt data.txt
aaab;10;2
bbbc;20;2
abc;30;1
cc;40;1
```

The differences between this and your currently accepted answer will be apparent when your input contains strings in patterns.txt that occur in the 2nd field of data.txt or contain regexp metacharacters or if your files are large or ....

Comment: Thank you very much for an awesome solution and great comments! :)

Comment: You're welcome. Going forward when posting questions 1) avoid using the word "pattern" as it can mean just about anything, use string or regexp or condition or whatever it is you really mean, and 2) put time into thinking of sample input that includes rainy day cases that could be hard for a script to get right so that when we/you test potential solutions against it we know if it works in general rather than just produces the expected output for some sunny day input.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with gnu awk, but may be is not as fast as it could be:

```
$ cat data 
aaab;10
bbbc;20
abc:30
cc:40

$ cat patterns
aaa
aa
bbb
ccc

$ awk -F"[:;]" 'FNR==NR{hash[$1]; next}{hash2[++c]=$0 ";" 1} \
{for (i in hash) if ($0~i) {hash2[c]=$0 ";" 2;break}} \
END{for (k=1;k<=length(hash2);k++) print hash2[k]}' patterns data
aaab;10;2
bbbc;20;2
abc:30;1
cc:40;1
```

Personally , i would go with grep :

```
grep -f patterns data   #this will bring the matching data
grep -v -f patterns data #this will bring the non matching data
```

All together :

```
printf '%s;%s\n' "$(grep -f patterns data)" "2" && printf '%s;%s\n' "$(grep -v -f patterns data) "1"
```

Comment: George, thank you for the solution, although I made a mistake in the original question (I by mistake put `:` instead of `,` as delimiter at a few places as correctly pointed out by karafka) your solution still works for both cases! Very good! :) I imagine the solution could be shorter if not needing to consider `:` as delimiter.

Comment: @Markus Solution will not be that shorter for one delimiter. The part `-F"[:;]" will have to be changed just to `-F"[;]"` - the rest code should remain the same.